# pyinstaller Recursion error: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert a .py to .exe using pyinstaller. When I type pyinstaller my_code.py everything seems to be working and after a couple of minutes the process stops and I get the recursion error. I have tried to create a my_code.spec file in the same folder, edit it and change the number of recursions but when I run pyinstaller apparently a new .spec is created since I can't find the sys.setrecursionlimit() command that I had previously added to the my_code.spec file.
I am running all the above from the anaconda command prompt and not from the command line but I think that this is not a problem since I have tried to convert to .exe a simple "hello world" script and it works perfectly.
I have python 3.6.3 installed.

Comment: What is inside my_code.py?

Comment: my_code.py is the python code that I want to convert to .exe Anyway I just solved it.
When I run pyinstaller my_code.py I immediately stop running with ctrl+c. Then I edit the .spec file that was created with
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)
And finally I run pyinstaller my_code.spec on the console.

Answer (score 6):

Please see this link:https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2919

The issue is with python 3.6, and most issues can be resolved by downgrading to python 3.5 to use pyinstaller.

If you are using anaconda3 this can be done by opening a command prompt and running:

```
conda update conda
```

And then running:

```
conda install python=3.5
```

Comment: But the error shown in the link is about Maximum Recursion depth, which I am not facing actually. But you still think it's better to use Py 3.5? Thanks

Comment: Pyinstaller should now be working with Python 3.5-3.7. I haven't seen this issue in any recent builds w/ 3.7.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to build a different environment for when wanting to make an executable python file. This should work to the python version your executable compiler works better. Usually, the older the python version the easiest is to compile.

Answer (score 0):

[The way suggested by alphabet5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51248441/2648551) took too long for me. I wanted to find another way.

What I did was to create another environment for `Python3.5` in *Anaconda Navigator*. Then, I activated the `Python3.5` environment (for example *py35*):

```
conda activate py35
```

Then, I installed necessary libraries such as `pyqt5`, `pyqtgraph`, `pyinstaller` etc. since *py35* is a newly created environment.

When I ran `pyinstaller` and didn't get any error.